# Change of limits in triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is

> If $f$ is continuous, show that
>   $$\int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y\int\limits_0^z f(t)dtdzdy =
>  \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^x (x-t)^2f(t)dt.$$

The solution is
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y\int\limits_0^z f(t)dtdzdy &= \int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y f(x)(y-t)dtdy = \int\limits_0^x\int\limits_t^x f(t)(y-t)dydt =\\&=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\left(\int\limits_t^x (y-t)dy\right)dt = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^x f(t)(x-t)^2dt,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
however, I can't understand first two equalities. Can anybody explain them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the double integral $\ \int\limits_0^y\int\limits_0^z f(t)dtdz\ $, the region over which the integration is carried out is $\ \left\{\left(t,z\right)\left\vert\, 0\le t\le z \le y\right. \right\}\ $. This must remain the same, regardless of the order in which the two single integrals are carried out.  When you integrate with respect to $\ z\ $, you have to do so for every value of $\ t\ $ in the interval $\ \left[0, y\right]\ $, and in the integral $\ z\ $ must run from $\ t\ $ to $\ y\ $. That is, the integral is
$$\ \int\limits_0^y\int\limits_t^y f(t)dzdt=\ \int\limits_0^y\left(\int\limits_t^y 1\right)dzf(t)dt = \int\limits_0^y\left(y-t\right) f(t)dt\ ,$$
 because $\ f(t)\ $ is independent of $\ z\ $.

Similarly, for the integral $\ \int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y\left(y-t\right) f(t)dtdy\ $, the region of integration is $\ \left\{\left(t,x\right)\left\vert\, 0\le t\le y \le x\right. \right\}\ $, so when you reverse the order of integration, $\ y\ $ must run from $\ t\ $ to $\ x\ $, and we get
$$\ \int\limits_0^x\int\limits_0^y \left(y-t\right)f(t)dtdy=\ \int\limits_0^x\left(\int\limits_t^x \left( y-t\right)\right)dyf(t)dt\ .$$

Comment: It seems you have a copy & paste error. The RHS of your second equations line is the same as the first. However, as can be seen from the middle part of your second line and as stated in the question, I believe it should be $\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^x f(t)(x-t)^2dt$ instead.

Comment: @John Omelian Yes, thank you. I didn't pay any attention the final step, not even enough to notice that it' s one you can do in your head.  The very last equation was, as you say, a copy-paste carryover from the one above, which I neglected to delete before saving my answer.